# More pythonic to convert bytes to string while processing urllib response instead of chr(int(x))

Tags: python, character-encoding, urllib

I am late convert to Python 3. I am trying to process output from a REST api for protein sequences using urllib.

In legacy python I could use:

```
self.seq_fileobj = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/{}.fasta".format(uniprot_id))
self.seq_header = self.seq_fileobj.next()
print "Read in sequence information for {}.".format(self.seq_header[:-1])
self.sequence = [achar for a_line in self.seq_fileobj for achar in a_line if achar != "\n"]
print("Sequence:{}\n".format("".join(self.sequence)))
```

For the same section of code in python 3, I use:

```
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
self.seq_fileobj = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/{}.fasta".format(uniprot_id),context=context)
self.seq_header = next(self.seq_fileobj)
print("Read in sequence information for {}.".format(self.seq_header.rstrip()))
self.b_sequence = [str(achar).encode('utf-8') for a_line in self.seq_fileobj for achar in a_line]
self.sequence = [chr(int(x)) for x in self.b_sequence]
```

I have read a little about string encoding and decoding to modify my list comprehension for python 3:

```
self.b_sequence = [str(achar).encode('utf-8') for a_line in self.seq_fileobj for achar in a_line]
self.sequence = [chr(int(x)) for x in self.b_sequence]
```

Although my code is working- is this the best way to achieve this result where I go from an array of bytes of ascii characters encoded with utf-8 to their resulting strings?. The chr(int(x)) bit is what seems un pythonic to me and I fear I may be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert the bytes to strings on a character-to-character basis. Since you want to strip out the newline characters, you can instead read the entire file as bytes, convert the bytes to strings with the `decode` method (which defaults to the `utf-8` encoding as you are using) and remove the newline characters using the `str.replace` method:

```
self.sequence = list(self.seq_fileobj.read().decode().replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: Thank you..this is so much cleaner and I now understand now that decode basically gets it done inside the list comprehension.

Comment: A string itself is a sequence and can be accessed like a `list`. There is no need to convert it to a `list` unless the content needs to be modified.